# How to get id or name of iframe using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have one iframe:

```
<iframe id="frame" name="frame" src="test.html"></iframe>
```

Now, I want to get id or name that iframe and alert it, I used:

```
if (document.getelementbyid('frame') = frame) alert('OK');
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: If you already know the ID, why do you need to get it?
also, be mindful of your capitalization.  Javascript is case sensitive.
`document.getElementById("frame").id`

Comment: also == is test for equality, = is assignment and getelementbyid is camel case and you likely meant `== "frame"` which does not make sense to get the frame by id and then test it is called frame

Comment: it's use for some script, ex: if (document.getelementbyid('frame') = frame) document.write('some code')

Comment: But that's basically just saying `if ('frame'=='frame')` in which case, it's just `if (true)`  which is pointless.

Comment: if you are trying to validate if the iframe exists, you can do this `if (document.getElementById("frame")!=null)`

Comment: Use `if(document.getElementById('frame') == frame) document.write('some code');` Javascript is case sensitive, so there is no native function getelementbyid(). Also, as @mplungjn stated, you are using an assignment (=), not a comparison (==) operator, so the condition will always be true. A debugger should tell you the relevant errors. Find out how to use a javascript debugger in a browser.

Comment: Perhaps are you trying to check if an iframe exists with the given id? Or are you trying to get the id of the iframe on which a page is loaded on (from such page)? Also "doesn't work" is not a great way to describe a problem... you should check the spelling as Trevor mentions Javascript is case sensitive (also if you actually wanted to make an assigment there, you put the variable first, otherwise, you probably want == or ===), besides that, tell us what is the behaviour you expect or want from your script.

Comment: Thanks all, but all is not work too, anything esle for help me ?

Answer (score 4):

```
var iframe = document.querySelector("iframe");

if(iframe .getAttribute("id") == "frame") {
   alert('iFrame has an ID called frame');
}
if(iframe .getAttribute("name") == "frame") {
   alert('The iFrame has a NAME called frame');
}
```

Comment: Small detail, but if you are going to do more than one thing with a DOM object, you should cache a reference to it in a variable and then access the properties of the object via that variable to avoid scanning the DOM multiple times for the same object.

Comment: Good point. I'll update the answer

Answer (score 1):

if you want to check iframe has existed and then id and name attribute try this

```
el = document.getElementById('frame')
if (el != null) {   
    alert('id :' + el.id)
    if (el.name!=""){
        alert('name: ' + el.name)
    }
    else{
        alert('frame do not have name attribute')
    }
}else{
    alert('frame do not exist')
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't check the `id` or `name` properties of the DOM object against a value. It only checks to see if the object was found.

Comment: @ScottMarcus apprently user just want to check that iframe has exist or not.by the way if added to check id and name attribute.Thanks for your comment

Comment: I retracted my down vote, but seems clear that the OP does *not* want to check if element exists, but does want to check the `id` or `name` properties. Also, I would *strongly* suggest that you edit your answer to include the curly braces around your `if` branches. While legal to omit them when the branch has only one statement to execute, it's a well-known anti-pattern to do so. And, given that SO is a knowledge base and learning tool, giving answers that include poorly structured code isn't a good thing.

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks ,I fixed it.

Comment: I don't think you understood @mplungjan. if `el` is not `null`, then it *will* have a `name` and an `id` property because the `HTMLIFrameElement` interface defines these. So `el.name != undefined` will *always* be true because even when these properties haven't been set, their default value is `""`. If you simply want to know if the `name` property has a value, just check  `el.name != ""`

Answer (score 1):

Just simply scanning the DOM for the element is one thing:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("frame"); // Note the captialization!
```

But, that won't get you the `id` or `name` attribute values. You'd need to go a little further for that:

```
console.log(iframe.id, iframe.name);
```

Also, JavaScript is case-sensitive and you have a few capitalization errors in your invocations of `.getElementById()`.

**Additionally, getting an element by its `id` only to compare it to the same `id` is pointless. Whatever you are trying to do, there is a better way to do it.**

Lastly, `document.write()` has very limited use cases. When you want to dynamically output content, prepare a placeholder for that output and then dynamically inject the content into that previously prepared container. In many cases, using `document.write()` will cause the entire currently loaded document to be unloaded.

```js
var p = document.getElementById("output");

var iframe = document.getElementById("frame"); // Note the captialization!
console.log(iframe.id, iframe.name);

// When comparing values in JavaScript, you need the double equal sign operator (==)
// which converts the types of the operands to the same type and then compares them,
// or the triple equal sign (===) operator which just compares the operands without
// data type conversion. A single equal sign will assign a value and, if used like
// you had it, would cause your if condition to always be true
if (document.getElementById('frame').id === "frame"){
  // Update the output area with the dynamic content
  output.textContent = "OK!";
} else {
  output.textContent = "NOT OK!";
}
```

```html
<iframe id="frame" name="frame" src="test.html"></iframe>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: @Theraot No. I am still editing the answer. As my answer states, just getting the element is not the same thing as getting the `id` or `name`.

Answer (score -2):

You need to pay attention on uppercase letters. This should be

```
document.getElementById('frame')
```

Also in if You are using one equal sign which is assignment operator. Comparing operator You should use are two equal signs, so whole if should looks like this

```
if (document.getElementById('frame') == frame) alert('OK');
```

But answering the question: every HTMLElement object (which You can get from methods like that `getElementById`) has properties like `id` and `name` which is what You want.

So You can assign gotten iframe and then use variable to get id and name:

```
let iframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
console.log(iframe.id, iframe.name);
```

`getElementsByTagName` returns all elements with passed tag as array so if You have only one iframe on site, You can get first element from returned array in the same var declaration.

Comment: Your code compares the DOM object reference against a value, not the `id` or `name`.

Comment: And `=` is an equal sign, not a question mark `?`

Comment: It's not work, anything else for help me ?

Comment: Fixed my answer sorry for that I didn't clearly answer Your question and for mistakes